# how to create custom video player with all controls

Tags: android

is any library is there for to play you-tube video as well as mp4 files, video player should contains all controls like play,pause,stop seek-to, get-frame, and video streaming etc. or can any one tell me how to create the same.

please help me.
thanks in advance..

Comment: [see this][1]

 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188346/android-how-to-create-video-player

Answer (score 1):

As Pandy said, use the MediaPlayer. Just drag it in from your eclipse UI editor and then work on it  as you would anything else in android such textviews, etc.

Take a look at the dev guide for more info
[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MediaPlayer%28%29)

Comment: can we play youtube videos on MediaPlayer.

Comment: but how to play youtube videos in mediaplayer, they are link, can you send me sample project.

Comment: take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716146/rtsp-youtube-link
its basically rtsp links that mediaplayer can actually play. quality is low, but it plays :D