# drawing Media Player UI for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, media-player

I am realizing my own media player am using ffmpeg for decoding and libjnigraphics(Bitmap,SurfaceView,...) for rendering.

I got it working now i want to get an attractive UI i want to display play/pause/stop/next buttons in the bottom of my screen with circular buttons etc like in the actual video players available in the market and in the following picture
[image]
How a similar UI is realized in android ?

I searched a lot over the net but i didn't find anything interesting

I would be thankfull if someone gives me tips about making similar UI

Comment: i've  already did all this work correctly what i want is tips for attractive ui similar to the one in the picture

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do you should take a look at this answer here:

[Android: How to create video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188346/android-how-to-create-video-player)

by [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) and also to his sample application [Vidtry](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry/tree).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: i've  already did all this work correctly what i want is tips for attractive ui similar to the one in the picture

Comment: Uh, I didn't see the picture because I'm behind a company proxy. Btw they're just Button, so I think you have to "style" them through xml with background or something like that. :)